# Кастомный чекбокс и событие onclick

Tags: customview, javascript

Верстальщик сделала кастомный чекбокс, мне нужно при клике на него что-то сделать. Пишу код

```
$('#conditions').click(function() { alert('12');});
```

не работает. Переписываю

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
$('#conditions').click(function() {
alert('12');}); 
});
```

не работает. Т.к. При использовании скрипта кастомизации генерируется див, и де факто клик происходит по нему, пишу аналогичные варианты, но уже для клика по этому диву - работать отказывается.

пробовал

```
$('#conditions').on('click', function()
```

аналогично.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где копать?

Comment: Добавьте пример на jsFiddle. Или покажите верстку. Сегодня много помех из-за электромагнитных возмущений. Телепатия не работает.

Comment: сделайте на событие change а не click :) а вообще из космоса подсказывают - у вас id conditions - не уникальный.

Comment: @Ozim, да-да, вы правы. Весь день, понимаете, какая напасть, какие-то помехи на прямой линии с коллективным бессознательным! Верстку, почему-то, вашу, увидеть не могу. Все как в тумане.  
Только какая-то обрывочная информация доходит до меня. Абсолютное позиционирование, перекрытие элементов, z-index, миссклик по элементу...  
Темное это дело, одним словом.

Comment: @VenZell ну включите логику, кастомный чекбокс работает, все ок, но события по клику не отрабатывает, нет вам правда нужно показать весь код?

Comment: @Ozim, работает css. Не факт, что проходит клик по чекбоксу, как вы того ожидаете.

Comment: @Ozim, да нам нужно показать тот код который с checkbox а именно, кусочек html и css, мы понятия не имеем как у вас это реализовано вашим верстальщиком, у меня всё отлично работает, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/yMDjc/

Comment: ок, сейчас я поколдую, там гору кода надо вставить, вставил, но оно у меня не работает.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uYPj6/7/
не могу заставить его работать там. Не умею пользоваться фиддлом, наверное.. Но выглядит как то так. там должен появляться див с картинкой вместо чекбокса.

Comment: вы знаете, вся проблема в js которым делается эта кастомизация,<s> я сходу не нашел</s>,  потому что она более чем полностью - говнокод. в общем вам нужно найти место в этом говнокоде, где оригинальный чекбокс меняется, и после этой смены поставьте там  `$(checkboxelement).trigger('myclick');`  и повесьте слушателя на это событие, а лучше переделайте способ кастомизации пока не поздно.

[вот тут работает](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/uYPj6/8/)

Comment: о, благодарю премного! А в чем там была трабла, если не секрет? почему на click не работало? И конвертируйте коммент в ответ, я приму

Comment: проблема в fiddle была в window.onload, а как я там отловил click, это не очень важно, поищите по коду, клик не работает в такой реализации, потому что input не потомок  созданного элемента.